# Problem with using function remove(..) from stdio.h C++

Tags: c++, stdio

Hello my question is why the following function fails to delete the file whose name is specified in dir1;
I use the function remove but it seems that there is some kind of a problem with it.
Please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test(char* dir1,char* dir2)
{

    FILE * file1,* file2;
    file1=fopen(dir1,"r");
    file2=fopen(dir2,"w");
    if(!file1){ return;}
    int inpch;
    char* string = new char[10];
    string[9]='\0';
    int br=0;

    do
    {   

        while((inpch=fgetc(file1))!=EOF)
        {
            string[br]=char(inpch);
            br++;
            if(br==9)break;
        }


        if(br!=9)
        {
            string[br]='\0';
            fputs(string,file2);


            return;
        }
        else
        {   
            fputs(string,file2);
            br=0;

        }


    }while(true);

    fclose(file1);
    remove(dir1);/// I DON"T UNDERSTAND WHY IT DOESN"T DELETE THE FILE.
    fclose(file2);
}
```

Comment: Do you (rather, does the program) have appropriate permission to remove the file?

Comment: @Michael: There are like 14 error cases for `unlink` and 13 for `rmdir` system calls that `remove` is calling. Are we going to ask OP 17 times about his sureness in one case or another? :)

Answer (score 4):

I guess at some point before exiting the `do-while` loop, the following `if` condition becomes true, and the function returns before it reaches to the end of the function, without even calling the `remove` function.

```
    if(br!=9)
    {
        string[br]='\0';
        fputs(string,file2);
        return; //<------------ here you're returning!
    }
```

Did you want to write `return` or `break`? Looks like its there the problem lies.

Comment: You've got an eagle eye, man. He should break on 9-th byte tho, if he gets lucky :)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you check for the return value and error code (errno) that tells you exactly why the function didn't succeed?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `remove` call with this :

```
if( remove( "myfile.txt" ) != 0 )
    perror( "Error deleting file" );
  else
    puts( "File successfully deleted" );
```

and it should tell you what happened.